# MS excel not coping data in correct format from csv file

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, formatting, csv

I am coping data from csv file

it contains tables

in that table there is column name `PostedDate`

when i copy that `PostedDate` column in excel it shows wrong formatting (ie instead of `/` it shows `-`)

following are my images

CSV file in notepad:
[image: CSV file in notepad]

Excel file:
[image: Excel file]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Why can't you import the file into Excel? Why must you copy/paste the data?

Comment: importing also gives same problem

Comment: Have you checked your computer's Regional settings? What is its date separator?

Comment: You could open the csv file in Notepad++ and use the CSV Lint plugin to reformat the datetime values to `yyyy-MM-dd`, and then copy and paste it into Excel, see https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/

Answer (score 1):

Your problems:

- CSV does not include any formatting information, so your computer will try to interpret these text strings as best it can.
- Your computer regional short date settings are `DMY`, with a date separator of the hyphen, but the CSV file date order is `MDY`

  - As a result, if the `D` <= 12 the date will be converted into an **incorrect** "real date".
  - Dates with `D` > 12 will be retained as text

The fix:

- **Import** the csv file using either Power Query or the Legacy Wizard.

  - Using the Legacy wizard, you will specify the date sequence of the CSV file at the time of importation
  - Using Power Query, you will go to Edit mode and set the date sequence by using the Set Data Types by Locale (and pick some country that uses MDY, eg: USA)
- The dates will still show your system separator in Excel. If you want to change that display, you will need to format the column with the separator you really want.

Other issues:

- Dates are stored as serial numbers with 1 = 1 Jan 1900

***Note***

- You could change your Windows Regional short date settings to match that of the CSV file. This would alter that across all of your window program.
- You could set the data types of the column to `Text`, but that would not allow you to use the information as Dates without converting them to real dates (which would be more complicated than importing them correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I have office365.I used Import data from Text/CSV. It displays the data correctly.
[image]